# Does second-order logic satisfy Craig interpolation for second-order languages?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, higher-order-logics

*(For simplicity, all languages are relational.)*

In analogy with *first-order* languages, say that a **second-order language** is a set of relation symbols of two kinds: *first-order* relation symbols and *second-order* relation symbols. Both types of symbols have a notion of arity; the arity of a first-order relation symbol is a natural number, and the arity of a second-order relation symbol is a finite string of natural numbers.

Given a second-order language $\Sigma=\langle\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2\rangle$ (with $\Sigma_i$ denoting the set of $i$th-order symbols of $\Sigma$), a **$\Sigma$-structure** is defined in the obvious way: as a *triple* $\mathcal{A}=(A; \mathfrak{I}_1,\mathfrak{I}_2)$ such that

- $A$ is a (nonempty) set,
- $\mathfrak{I}_1$ is a map sending each $R\in\Sigma_1$ with arity $n$ to a subset of $A^n$, and
- $\mathfrak{I}_2$ is a map sending each $S\in\Sigma_2$ with arity $\alpha$ to a subset of $\mathcal{P}(A^{\alpha(1)})\times...\times\mathcal{P}(A^{\alpha(\vert\alpha\vert)})$.

There is an obvious semantics for second-order logic over a structure in a second-order language (note that this extends the "full"/"standard" semantics, rather than the Henkin semantics, for second-order logic in the context of first-order languages). I'm curious whether Craig interpolation holds in this broader framework:

> Suppose $\varphi,\theta$ are $\mathsf{SOL}$-sentences in second-order languages $\Sigma,\Pi$ respectively such that $\varphi\models\theta$. Must there be a $\mathsf{SOL}[\Sigma\cap\Pi]$-sentence $\delta$ such that $\varphi\models\delta$ and $\delta\models\theta$?

Craig interpolation for $\mathsf{SOL}$ is trivial in the context of *first-order* languages, since we can appropriately quantify out the non-shared symbols. But that doesn't work here. In fact, I suspect that the answer is **negative** via an easy construction, but I don't immediately see it.

*(Incidentally, it's possible that my restriction to relational languages is less benign for these purposes than it appears. I'm happy to generalize in the obvious way to allow function symbols!)*

Comment: In particular, this would imply that in the standard model of arithmetic, $\Delta^2_1=\bigcup_k\Sigma^1_k$ (and more generally, any pair of disjoint $\Sigma^2_1$ sets of reals can be separated by a $\bigcup_k\Sigma^1_k$ set). I find this very hard to believe.

Comment: In fact, the satisfaction predicate for second-order formulas (say, with a single unary free set variable) should be a counterexample: it’s $\Sigma^2_1$-definable (hence also $\Pi^2_1$), right?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Seems right. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Sorry for the continued bother. Could you add this as an answer so I can accept it? (If you'd prefer not to, I'm happy to write up my own CW-answer to cover the material.)

Comment: I’m sorry, but I’m too busy at this time to write a proper answer. Feel free to write one yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is just an expansion of Emil Jerabek's comments above; I've made it CW to avoid reputation gain, and will delete this if he posts an answer of his own.*

Craig interpolation can be rephrased as a "syntactic separation" property: the statement $$\varphi\models\psi$$ can be rephrased as $$\emptyset\models\exists\mathfrak{R}(\varphi[\mathfrak{R}])\rightarrow\exists\mathfrak{S}(\varphi[\mathfrak{S}])$$ for some appropriate objects $\mathfrak{R},\mathfrak{S}$ corresponding to the *un*common parts of the languages of $\varphi,\psi$ respectively. Now if our "base logic" is first-order then this is broadly speaking where the story ends, but using second-order logic as our "base" gives us a lot more power.

Specifically, since we can pin down $\mathcal{N}=(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$ up to isomorphism, we can "localize" the syntactic separation result above into a separation result for sets of natural numbers: if "fully-second-order" logic had the Craig interpolation property then any two disjoint $\Sigma^2_1$ subsets of $\mathcal{N}$ could be separated by a second-order-definable set of naturals, but this is impossible (by Tarski) since the usual-second-order theory of $\mathcal{N}$ is $\Delta^2_1$.

---

This raises a natural follow-up question:

- Is there a "reasonably natural" and "not too strong" extension of second-order logic which has the interpolation property for second-order languages?

The point of the "not too strong" requirement is that there is an obvious extension of $\mathsf{SOL}$ which has the interpolation property for second-order languages - **third**-order logic (which then loses interpolation for third-order languages, and so forth)!

Comment: Sorry, I apparently *didn't* make it CW at first. Fixed!